# Calling Stored procedure using iBatis, unable to retrieve OUT parameter

Tags: java, stored-procedures, ibatis

I have the below procedure to avoid duplicate inserts:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE spCheckDuplicate
(in_price IN VARCHAR2(20),             
in_drug IN  VARCHAR2(20),          ,
out_count OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
out_count :=0;
    BEGIN
        SELECT count(*) into out_count
        FROM DRUG_TABLE where DRUGNAME=in_drug and PRICE=in_price ;
    EXCEPTION
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            out_count := 0;
    END;



IF (out_count = 0)
     THEN
    INSERT INTO DRUG_TABLE(DRUGNAME,PRICE)
    VALUES(in_drug,in_price )
  END;
  END IF;


END ;
```

I need to call this stored procedure from my j2ee application, using iBatis for the same, I am unable to retrieve my out parameter which the stored procedure returns (returning the count of drug+price combination).

```
**Ibatis xml**


       <procedure id="avoidDuplicateInsert" 
                          parameterClass="DrugVO" resultClass="DrugVO">
               { call spCheckDuplicate( #price#,#drug#,#count#)}
        </procedure>
```

This does not work, unable to get count. While similar procedure works fine with only IN parameters.

```
**JavaDAO class**

result  = (DrugVO) this.queryForObject("avoidDuplicateInsert",DrugVO);
    System.out.println("result count" + result.getCount());
```

I get a nullpointer here